# Android NDK 15c error with python-for-android/kivy python 2

Tags: python, android-ndk, buildozer

At compiling the code using buildozer the code  gives an error, I think its abot (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)
bt not sure.

I copied the error (log 2) and majore specification in buildozer spec file.

**Error Log**

```
[INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
Exception in thread background thread for pid 14878:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /home/sherif/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c/ndk-build V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a

  STDOUT:
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.    
jni/Android.mk:11: extraneous text after 'ifeq' directive
/home/sherif/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c/build/core/build-binary.mk:688: Android NDK: Module cjpeg depends on undefined modules: cutils    
/home/sherif/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c/build/core/build-binary.mk:701: *** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 916, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 913, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 514, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 147, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 192, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx)
  File "pythonforandroid/build.py", line 572, in build_recipes
  File "/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master/pythonforandroid/recipes/jpeg/__init__.py", line 29, in build_arch
    super(JpegRecipe, self).build_arch(arch)
  File "pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 710, in build_arch
  File "pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 175, in shprint
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2: 

  RAN: /home/sherif/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c/ndk-build V=1 APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a

  STDOUT:
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.    
jni/Android.mk:11: extraneous text after 'ifeq' directive
/home/sherif/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c/build/core/build-binary.mk:688: Android NDK: Module cjpeg depends on undefined modules: cutils    
/home/sherif/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c/build/core/build-binary.mk:701: *** Android NDK: Aborting (set APP_ALLOW_MISSING_DEPS=true to allow missing dependencies)    .  Stop.


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=master --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,pil --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/sherif/Desktop/P2/.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

**Changes in Spec-file**

```
> # (str) Title of your application title =  Crysteg

> # (str) Package name package.name = master 
> # (str) Application versioning (method 1) version = 3.0

> # comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy 
requirements = kivy,pil

> # change the major version of python used by the app 
osx.python_version = 2

> # Kivy version to use 
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

> # (list) Permissions
> #android.permissions = INTERNET
> 
> # (int) Android API to use
> #android.api = 19
> 
> # (int) Minimum API required
> #android.minapi = 9
> 
> # (int) Android SDK version to use
 #android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use a
ndroid.ndk = 15

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
 #android.ndk_path = 
android.ndk_path = ~/Downloads/android-ndk-r15c-linux-x86_64/android-ndk-r15c
# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)

 #android.sdk_path = 
android.sdk_path = ~/Downloads/android-sdk-linux

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
> # when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
> # android.skip_update = False

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86 android.arch = armeabi-v7a



# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
 # p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output)) log_level = 2

 # (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True) warn_on_root = 1

 # (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
 # build_dir = ./.buildozer


# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin
```

No error with using ndk9c but the app crash at launching.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the second error, edit [jpeg/build-static.patch](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/jpeg/build-static.patch#L10): remove the word `libcutils`.

Regarding *"extraneous text after 'ifeq' directive"*, I believe it is just a warning, and can be ignored.